# Python and Pandas NoneType error for empty list

Tags: python, pandas, list, nonetype

I have a form which takes a list of inputs via html (searchinput) and adds it to a query in python.

```
    searchterms = []
    searchterms = request.values.get('searchinput').strip().split(', ')
    filtered = pd.concat([df.query("Drug.str.contains('|'.join(@searchterms), na=False, case=False, regex=True)", engine='python')])
    return render_template('drugsafety.html', tables=[filtered.to_html(classes='data')], titles=['na', 'Drug List'])
```

This gives

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

If I then feed in a value like searchterms = ["foobar"] it works and will even take the form inputs without error.

How can I get around this initial needing a value to boot it into life?

**edit**

```
    searchterms = []
    if searchterms is not None:
        searchterms = request.values.get('searchinput').strip().split(', ')
        filtered = pd.concat([ df.query("Drug.str.contains('|'.join(@searchterms), na=False, case=False, regex=True)", engine='python')])            
    else:  
        searchterms = ["Foo"]
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: It means that no value "searchinput" was found and get defaults to None instead.

Comment: Do you know of a way I can fix it? Putting a not none check doesnt change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put default value (`''`) in `.get`:

```py
# put `''` in .get():
searchterms = request.values.get('searchinput', '').strip().split(', ')
```